# Power BI From and To Date Filtering with One Slicer

Tags: powerbi, filtering, slicers

I've a simple (hope so) question.
I've got a table where I have a start date column and an end date column.
I can add two slicer to filter the period, but I would like to filter with just one slider, like shown on this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W5n8-5Q7mII&ab_channel=RADACAD but I'm missing the point of creating the other date table like he does. Can someone else help me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can create the date table using Power Query or Dax.

https://radacad.com/all-in-one-script-to-create-date-dimension-in-power-bi-using-power-query
https://radacad.com/all-in-one-script-to-create-calendar-table-or-date-dimension-using-dax-in-power-bi

Simply you can use `CALENDAR()` or `CALENDARAUTO()` function in Dax.

```
Date = CALENDAR(<start date>, <end date>)
Date = CALENDARAUTO()
```

Those will help you create the date table.